# How to access dynamic object stored in session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session

In PHP we can store/access the associative array in session.
How can i access them using asp.net mvc4.

I have set the variable in session like:

```
Session["User"] = new { UserName = "abc", Email= "a@a.com", UserType="User" };
```

I need some mechanism to access the values like UserName form session "User" like-

```
string user = Session["User"]["UserName"]
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example what you are putting in the session is not a dynamic object, but an instance of an anonymous class. This however will not work, as in order to access the properties of the object when reading it out from the session, you would have to cast it to the correct type, in this case the anonymous class. As you do not know the name of the anonymous class (that's why it's anonymous), you cannot do this cast.
There are three ways around this:

1. use a named class
2. use a dictionary
3. use a dynamic object

### 1. Use a named class

This one is really simple, just create a class (or struct) with the properties you need:

```
public class UserData {
  public string UserName {get; set;}
  public string Email {get; set;}
  public string UserType {get; set;}
}
```

Then use instances of this class to store the data in the session:

```
Session["User"] = new UserData {UserName = "abc", Email= "a@a.com", UserType="User"};
```

and access it like this:

```
var user = (UserData)Session["User"]; 
var userName = user.UserName;
```

In this case you loose the "dynamism", as you have to declare all properties up-front, but you get some compile time checking in return, and that is a good thing. I would go for this solution unless there is a very good reason for storing dynamic values.

### 2. Use a dictionary

Here you store a `Dictionary<string, string>` in the session:

```
Session["User"] = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"UserName", "abc"}, {"Email", "a@a.com"}, {"UserType", "User"} };
```

and to access it:

```
var userDict = (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["User"];
var userName = userDict["UserName"];
```

### 3. Use a dynamic object

This one is not that different from using a dictionary in that it provides no compile time type check, but provides a bit nicer syntax.

```
dynamic userData = new ExpandoObject();
userData.UserName = "abc";
userData.Email = "a@a.com";
userData.UserType = "User";
Session["User"] = userData;
```

or, as @James noted in a comment, you can also use an anonymous type here as well, just like you had in your original example:

```
Session["User"] = new {UserName="abc", Email="a@a.com", UserType="User"};
```

and to access it:

```
dynamic userData = Session["User"];
var userName = userData.UserName;
```

Comment: is there any differences of using Dictionary and dynamic? What is best practice for Session?

Comment: As I wrote, I would really go with the named class solution to get the benefit of compile time type checking. The difference between the two other solutions is really just syntactical, as internally  ExpandoObject uses a Dictionary to store the values.

Comment: @csgero to use a `dynamic` object you don't need to explicitly create an `ExpandoObject`. You can use the code as the OP already has it by creating an anonymous type and simply casting to `dynamic`.

Answer (score 1):

You have created an anonymous object so you should be able to cast that directly to `dynamic`

```
string user = ((dynamic)Session["User"]).UserName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary: `Dictionary<string, string>` or `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```
var user = new Dictionary<string, string>();
user.Add("UserName", "abc");
user.Add("Email", "a@a.com");
user.Add("UserType", "User");
Session["User"] = user;
```

and use it:

```
string user = ((Dictionary<string, string>)Session["User"])["UserName"];
```